# React - deliver menu options from child element to parent's menu

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components:

Child container,
Parent container - this component renders both child container and a menu which get's props.children and renders them

I want to pass elements from the child container to the menu in the parent container for rendering.

what is the best way to do that?
I know I can create a callback on the parent container and pass the elements through it, but I don't think it's the right way to do it...

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Menu>{/*Render Child's options here*/}</Menu>
                <Child {/*Some way to pass DOM elements from Child to Main*/} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // Pass DOM elements to parent in order to render them in the Menu
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Menu = props => <div>{props.children}</div>;
```

Comment: You should post the code you want to get help or an example of it.

Comment: I updated the question...